# Как сохранить базу SQL Server в SQL скрипт?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть база SQL Server. Какими средствами возможно перевести ее в SQL (или T-SQL) скрипт так, чтобы он сам создавал все таблицы и так далее?

Answer (score 5):

Добрый день.

Ваша задача элементарно решается в любой версии SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio):

1. Правой кнопкой кликаете на название базы данных (не таблицы) и выбираете в задачах **Генерация скрипта**
2. Далее выбираете необходимые таблицы
3. Нажимаете расширенные настройки и ставите галочку напротив пункта **схема и дата** (если вам помимо структуры нужны и данные)

Фактически для всей этой операции используется PowerShell, поэтому если такая задача стоит для группы серверов и вы хотите ее оптимизировать, то можно начать [здесь](https://github.com/ctrlbold/dbatools) и посмотреть [сюда](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)

Answer (score 2):

[The SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5498) обеспечивает способ публикации базы данных в единый T-SQL скрипт, который может быть использован для воссоздания базы данных (как схемы, так и данных).

Comment: Можете подправить ссылку, интересно что это за инструмент такой?

Answer (score 0):

В случае MySQL + phpMyAdmin делаете в последнем экспорт и радуетесь жизни =)В Вашем же вопросе ведь подразумевается сервер SQL от Microsoft? Для него аналогичных встроенных средств для создания резервных копий такого типа мне неизвестно.

Comment: Кому полезно знать о том, что Вам что-то не известно? В вопросе не подразумевается, а явно сказано, что речь о MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

используйте утилиту mysqldump

```
mysqldump -uLOGIN -PPORT -hHOST -pPASS DBNAME > dump.sql
```

Comment: mssql путаете с mysql